# how to adjust react material ui pagination spacing/width on smaller screens

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react-material ui pagination component where I have rows per page option along with forward,backward,first_page and last_page options like shown below

[image]

Pagination render code:

```
<TablePagination
        component="div"
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50, 100]}
        colSpan={20}
        count={totalProducts}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        labelRowsPerPage="Rows per page"
        SelectProps={{
          inputProps: { "aria-label": "rows per page" },
          native: true
        }}
        onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        ActionsComponent={subProps => (
          <Pagination {...subProps} totalProducts={totalProducts} />
        )}
      />
```

Is there a way where for smaller screens , I can hide the rows per page option or move the pagination component towards left. Basically making the component responsive

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think just removing the rows per page will help your cause.

From the documentation for **rowsPerPageOptions**

> Customizes the options of the rows per page select field. If less than two options are available, no select field will be displayed.

So basically, if you pass 
`rowsPerPageOptions={[]}` should do the trick.

You can use [Hidden](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/) to toggle between those as below.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivetable-nw0vk)

```
<>
  <Hidden smUp>
   <TablePagination
     rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
     component="div"
     count={rows.length}
     rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
     page={page}
     onChangePage={handleChangePage}
     onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
   />
 </Hidden>
 <Hidden smDown>
   <TablePagination
   rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20]}
   component="div"
   count={rows.length}
   rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
   page={page}
   onChangePage={handleChangePage}
   onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
  />
 </Hidden>
</>
```

And the table is already responsive. Do let me know.

Comment: If you use the `useMediaQuery` hook then you only need one `TablePagination` instance with `rowsPerPageOptions={matches ? [] : [5, 10, 15, 20]}`